# Make an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle, knowing a vertex or a side

Tags: android, canvas, geometry

I'm learning Android and now I'm experimenting with the Canvas class.

I would like to draw a regular (equilateral) triangle inscribed into a known circle.

I think there must be a easier way to do it than getting into trigonomery, pythagoras,...

Comment: as far as I know thats the "easy" way, however I'll take a look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the trig is the most straightforward method that I've found. Below is a function for drawing an equilateral triangle in the normal, "pointing upward" orientation. I've posted a more sophisticated implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/3843841) that also handles rotating the triangle.

```
private void drawCircumscribedTriangle(Canvas canvas, float circleCenterX, float circleCenterY, float radius, Paint paint) {
    float xOffsetFromCenter = FloatMath.cos((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;
    float yOffsetFromCenter = FloatMath.sin((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;

    canvas.drawLine(circleCenterX, circleCenterY - radius, circleCenterX + xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(circleCenterX + xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterX - xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(circleCenterX - xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterX, circleCenterY - radius, paint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You don't know how much I've tried, and failed. I wish I could give you reputation, but I have 6 still. When I can I'll give you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Acj, I got it, But it wasn't exactly what I wanted, because I wanted it to be filled (It's my fault because I didn't specify it).

Anyway, I adapted Acj's code to my needs, and here it is:

```
private void drawCircumscribedTriangle(Canvas canvas, float circleCenterX, float circleCenterY, float radius, Paint paint) {

        float xOffsetFromCenter = FloatMath.cos((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;
        float yOffsetFromCenter = FloatMath.sin((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        path.moveTo(circleCenterX, circleCenterY - radius);
        path.lineTo(circleCenterX + xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter);
        path.lineTo(circleCenterX - xOffsetFromCenter, circleCenterY + yOffsetFromCenter);
        path.lineTo(circleCenterX, circleCenterY - radius);
        path.lineTo(circleCenterX, circleCenterY - radius);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Once more, all the merit is for Acj

Answer (score 0):

As `FloatMath.cos(float)` is deprecated since API 23, this answer to a tricky equilateral question needs the following lines of its code updating to

```
float xOffsetFromCenter =  ((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;
float yOffsetFromCenter =  ((float)Math.PI/6) * radius;
```